# Pages resolve at different URLs (different capitalizations)

Tags: permalinks, redirect, slug

I've always considered these to be two different URLs:

https://oursite.com/fun/

https://oursite.com/Fun/

On our site, the same page loads when entering each URL.

Did something change in WordPress to act this way? Is this default? I thought WP used to redirect to the permalink...

I think preferred behaviour would be to consider them the same, and always redirect e.g. `/Fun/` to `/fun/` (the canonical URL / permalink).

Our current permalink settings are `Post Name: https://www.oursite.ca/sample-post/` (second to last option, right above "Custom Structure."

PS - Unfortunately we're getting split entries in Google Analytics as a result of this behaviour.

Comment: Do you have a `<link rel="canonical" href="/fun/" />` in the header?

Comment: I am surprised by this. As far as I can tell the slug is getting lowercased before it gets to get_page_by_path() but I can't find where at first glance. (I had wondered if it was DB collation in there.)

Comment: Actually maybe you need to tell analytics to use the canonical URL yourself (/ get your analytics plugin to): https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/124459

Comment: Hi @Rup - yes we do, but that won't solve our Google Analytics problem. And unfortunately it doesn't seem GA4 has filters like UA did so we can't edit the data on the way in. I mean, perhaps something could be done with Tag Manager, but really, I'd like the website to fix it... I don't like the idea of people sharing bad links.

Comment: And yes @Rup, for some reason I thought WP handled this out of the box, but either it's changed, or is server-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Have you moved servers recently? In years past, Windows servers always treated them differently than on unix servers.

Barring that, you can edit your .htaccess file to convert all URLs to lowercase. Here's a guide editing depending if you have access to httpd.conf file or not;

https://www.rewriteguide.com/apache-enforce-lower-case-urls/

As suggested by @Rup, a canonical URL should take care of it all too.

Comment: I can confirm this is happening on two separate servers, which are both running Apache. I'm wondering if this is a change in WordPress..

Comment: I ended up using a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/lh-force-lowercase-urls/ instead of rewriting manually. I'm going to leave this open for a bit longer to see if any other info comes in, and then will accept if not. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear you got around it with a plugin.  I haven't seen this issue on any of the sites we manage, even the ones at GoDaddy.  Definitely odd.

Comment: Interesting @ConorTreacy. Just curious, does this mean that your sites redirect to lowercase, or 404? Would like to know what kind of behaviour you are seeing currently! Thanks. =)